# Adding labels to map legend

Tags: d3.js

I can't quite get this.  Trying to modify:
https://bl.ocks.org/duspviz-mit/9b6dce37101c30ab80d0bf378fe5e583

to be able add low value to the left of the bar and high value to right.  If anyone could point in the right direction, or show another example, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3.js - starting and ending tick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753126/d3-js-starting-and-ending-tick)

Comment: As referred above, use `.domain().nice()` to add the first (low value) and last (high value) ticks. And as @riov8 mentions in the answer, increase the svg width or add margins.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the ticks of the axis for the boundary of the domain.

Made the svg a bit bigger to fit the texts

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis line, .axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
svg{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="legend1"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var w = 300, h = 50;

    var key = d3.select("#legend1")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w+100)
      .attr("height", h+50);

    var legend = key.append("defs")
      .append("svg:linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient")
      .attr("x1", "0%")
      .attr("y1", "100%")
      .attr("x2", "100%")
      .attr("y2", "100%")
      .attr("spreadMethod", "pad");

    legend.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "0%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#f7fcf0")
      .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    legend.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "33%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#bae4bc")
      .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    legend.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "66%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#7bccc4")
      .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    legend.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "100%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#084081")
      .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

    key.append("rect")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h - 30)
      .style("fill", "url(#gradient)")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50,10)");

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([300, 0])
      .domain([68, 12]);

    var yAxis = d3.axisBottom()
      .scale(y)
      .ticks(5);

    key.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50,30)")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -30)
      .attr("dy", "0")
      .attr("dx", "0")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("axis title");
    var extras = key.select(".y.axis").selectAll(".dummy")
       .data(y.domain())
       .enter()
       .append("g")
       .attr("class", "tick")
       .attr("transform", d => `translate(${y(d)},0)` );
    extras.each( function (d) {
        d3.select(this).append("line").attr("stroke", "#000").attr("y2", 6);
        d3.select(this).append("text").attr("fill", "#000").attr("y", 9).attr("dy", "0.71em").text(d);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```