# How do I align tick values/label properly below the tick line

Tags: svg, d3.js, canvas, legend

I am working on continuous color legend using d3.interpolateViridis. I have problem in aligning the legend tick values. I want to display my domain values horizontally(below tick but in straign line and not slant).

Here is my code snippet for tick label:

```
const margin = { top: 10, right: 60, bottom: 10, left: 2 };

const legendaxis = axisRight(legendscale)
.scale(legendscale)
.tickSize(16)
.tickValues(legendscale.domain());

//other code

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.style("font-size", "14px")
.style("font-weight", "700")
.attr(
"transform",
"translate(" +
(80 - margin.left - margin.right + 3) +"," +margin.top +")")
.call(legendaxis);
```

I have also shared Fiddle link :
https://jsfiddle.net/shru90/j8hLq1b2/10/

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tja9Lwcy/) with the ticks rotated and translated to account for the location of transform-origin.

Comment: Although I just added a transformation to your original code. There are few problems.

1. Code you referred to uses a very old version of d3 (v4) latest version is v7
2. Instead of first rendering the canvas vertically and then rotating it, it's better to just render a horizontal canvas. That way it becomes very easy to render the axis by simply using `d3.axisBottom`, so you won't have to rotate the tick individually. [Link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngw58apt/)
3. Over at [Observable](https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-legend) you will find a readymade function and how to use it.

Comment: @Shreshth Thanks for the solution and inputs. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Shreshth I have edited a bit fiddle link shared by you according to my requirement. Can u help me displaying the exact max domain value in it. Currently label display as 38 but I need it to be 0.38 . https://jsfiddle.net/shru90/5tu6s2vg/2/

Comment: Also now it shows 38 - 0.0, but it should be 0.0 - 0.38 (min to max and not max to min).

Comment: To show end ticks, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21767045/1773808) describes a good approach (without removing other tick values as in your fiddle.)

Comment: As for 0.38 showing as 38, that's because the tick value is overflowing out of the SVG element. Adjusting the margins and translating the axis will fix that. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shreshth/ubpLmzf6/14/) with both changes above.

Comment: About min to max (or the other way around) you can flip either the range or the domain depending on which color corresponds to which value. [width, 0] → [0, width] for range or [0, 0.38] → [0.38, 0]

Comment: @Shreshth Thanks for the solution as well as as for the inputs. It worked.